# How can I fix flex 50% layout issue in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have a small example of flex layout and I have some problem with Safari (Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8))

So there is a content and inside of it there are four boxes, with the layout of 2x2. At the bottom there is a footer section.
I would like to place the boxes inside the content div to fill its height by 50% height and width. But in Safari it seems that it ignores the footer section and it places the boxes to align to the full page.

So here it what I want to achieve and it works in chrome:
[image]

And this is what it looks like in Safari:
[image]

I managed to try it in High Sierra where there is a newer Safari (Ver. 11) and it WORKS. So it must be a bug, but can we handle this in Safari 10? Thank you!

Here it is my code

HTML:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.footer {
  opacity: 0.7;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>    
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `content` is a flex column item you don't use `height` to make it fill its parent, you use `flex-grow`.

Remove the height on `content` and add `flex-grow: 1`

```
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;                    /*  added  */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

*Also no need for `width: 100%`, it does that by default*

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  background: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.footer {
  opacity: 0.7;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>    
  </div>

  <div class="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With your solution I managed to fix my problem is Safari!  :)